# Stacking percentages out of total using dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a data similar to

[image]

```
 Month      Material     Sales
   2            A         500
   2            A         300
   5            A         700
   1            B         400
   2            B         300
   4            C        1200
   2            C         500
```

I would like to display percentage of each material sales over total sales under Month dimension with dc.rowChart.

On month 2 for material A percentage will be %50 . Because on month 2 total sales are 1600 and A's sales are 800 . For material B percentage will be %18,75 because B's sales are 300 on month 2 . and so on.

So far i did below logic . But it doesn't display any data

```
var monthDim=ndx.dimension(function (d) {return +d.Month;});                                       

   var totalGroup = monthDim.group().reduce(
    /* callback for when data is added to the current filter results */
    (p, v) => {
        ++p.count;       
        p.Sales += v.Sales;          
        return p;
    },
    /* callback for when data is removed from the current filter results */
    (p, v) => {
        --p.count;       
        p.Sales -= v.Sales;           
        return p;
    },
    /* initialize p */
    () => ({
        count: 0,
        Sales: 0,      
    })
);
```

then find total sales :

```
var salesTotal= ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.Sales; });
var salesTotalGroup = salesTotal.groupAll().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.Sales; });
```

Now I want to combine these to variable on bar chart. I know they don't seem to work together. But that is what I came up with.

```
var chart= dc.rowChart('#salespercentagechart')
                 .width(400)
                 .height(350)
                 .elasticX(true)
                 .dimension(monthDim)
                 .group(totalGroup )      
                 .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value.Sales / salesTotalGroup;} )                
                 .ordering(function (d) { return -d.key; })
```

Any idea is perfect for me. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, this is possible, but there are three dimensions and the row chart unfortunately doesn't support stacking. You could do a stacked bar or line/area chart, or a line series chart.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I selected stacked  area chart . It shows what I want.

Comment: Do you man that you got it working? I did see a few problems in your code above, perhaps you could post an answer to your own question if it works now. Otherwise I will answer.

Comment: Please answer . Actually i can't seem to find percentage. I can only display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Counting sum of each category and total

You can use the crossfilter group custom reduction to calculate the total for each material at the same time as the overall total:

```
var totalGroup = monthDim.group().reduce(
    /* callback for when data is added to the current filter results */
    (p, v) => {
        p.byMaterial[v.Material] = (p.byMaterial[v.Material] || 0) + v.Sales;  
        p.total += v.Sales;
        return p;
    },
    /* callback for when data is removed from the current filter results */
    (p, v) => {
        p.byMaterial[v.Material] -= v.Sales;  
        p.total -= v.Sales;
        return p;
    },
    /* initialize p */
    () => ({
        byMaterial: {},
        total: 0,      
    })
);
```

This is sort of the canonical way to aggregate multiple stacks at once1

- keep an object keyed on the stack names
- when adding, treat undefined as 0 by using `|| 0`
- when removing, `p.byMaterial[v.Material]` will always be defined so `-=` is safe

Now `totalGroup.all()` will produce

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": {
      "byMaterial": {
        "B": 400
      },
      "total": 400
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "value": {
      "byMaterial": {
        "A": 800,
        "B": 300,
        "C": 500
      },
      "total": 1600
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 4,
    "value": {
      "byMaterial": {
        "C": 1200
      },
      "total": 1200
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 5,
    "value": {
      "byMaterial": {
        "A": 700
      },
      "total": 700
    }
  }
]
```

#### Initializing stacks in a loop

It's convenient to define the chart stacks in a loop:

```
var materials = d3.set(data, d => d.Material);
materials.values().sort().forEach((material, i) => {
  const accessor = d => (d.value.byMaterial[material] || 0) / d.value.total * 100;
  if(i === 0)
    chart.group(totalGroup, material, accessor);
  else
    chart.stack(totalGroup, material, accessor);  
});
```

We use d3.set to find all the unique values of `d.Material`, then loop over them. dc.js has [an annoying design bug](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/797) that you have to call `.group()` the first time even though it has the same parameters as `.stack()`, thus the `if(i === 0)`.

#### The accessor computes percentage

```
const accessor = d => (d.value.byMaterial[material] || 0) / d.value.total * 100;
```

It reads byMaterial, again defaulting `undefined` to 0 if that material did not exist in the month, then divides by the total and multiplies by 100 to get the percentage.

#### Rest of chart definition

```
var chart= dc.lineChart('#salespercentagechart')
    .width(400)
    .height(350)
    .renderArea(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .dimension(monthDim)
    .x(d3.scaleLinear()).elasticX(true)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(300).y(50))
    //.ordering(function (d) { return -d.key; });
```

[image: screenshot of stacked area/line chart]

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/frex9h48/85/).

Comment: Hello @Gordon. Thank you very much.  On title when  i want to display percentage of each material , on all points  it shows percentage of  chart.group material. On your example it is material A,  Is there a way i can dispaly all of them percentage when i go to data point on chart ?